# Hold HTTP servlet request threads for reloading business config object

Tags: java, servlets, thread-safety, queue, thread-synchronization

I need to Hot load or Reload business configuration / object at runtime in http servlet.

`Config` object is generated by reading a file during servlet `init()`. I need to reload this object when file is changed / updated..

```
public void init() {
    Config config = initializeConfigFile();
}
```

**Task 1** would be to have a thread periodically monitor file contents and if changed re-create config object from changed file.. I think this can be achieved by having some hash like md5 on file contents.. check if new hash changed..

```
public void run() {
    // Read file
    // Generate hash of file contents
    // Compare with previous hash
    // If different set a flag to hold threads
    // configFileChanged = true;
}
```

**Task 2** hold request threads until new config object is created. As this happens at runtime there might be request threads already accessing old config object and I can't just swap the config object as this might produce unexpected behavior. So I need to wait until all the threads already accessing the old config are done.

So I need suggestions for task 2.. I have not explored much of java advanced threading and queue based API's
For now thinking of some queue which holds request threads.

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
    if (configFileChanged) {
     synchronized (ActionServlet.class) {
        while (configFileChanged) {
            if (queue.isEmpty) {
                config = initializeConfigFile();
                configFileChanged = false;
            } else {
               sleep(2000);
            }
        }
    }
    }
    queue.insert(Thread.currentThread());
    // perform task using config object
    queue.remove();
}
```

Also suggest improvizations for task 1, if any..

Thanks..

Comment: First task can be done using [WatchingService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html)

Answer (score 0):

Bad way for both tasks:

For task 1:
Checking file regularry is not a logical process while you can have an observer/monitor for the file, in other word, check the new config once the file is changed(file monitor using `java.nio.file`)

For task 2:
If and if the container is not configured/overridden to create new instance for each request. --> The default/std behavior is having ONE object of the Servlet, and invoke the instance for each request via a thread, so for this a `synchronized void reload()` method would help.
During the `reload()` method run, because it locks the Servlet object, All new requests will be hold till the `reload()` finishes it's job.

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
 //servlet business
}
//the reload is called by the file monitor
//The synchronized method will hold all new requests
synchronized void reload(){/*applying new configs*/}
```

Besides having a file(external) observer might not look safe and logical, I suggest having an external applciation which monitors the file and informs the web context by calling a servlet(maybe `/friends/reload_config`) where there is a servlet mapped to `/friends/reload_config` which will call `reload()` method.

You may check the request ip in `/friends/reload_config` servlet in order to ensure the request is generated by local app(not from net)